# How does iOS determine which share extensions are enabled by default?

Tags: ios, share, ios-app-extension, ios-sharesheet

Some apps have their 'Share Extensions' enabled by default when installing the app. Flickr is an example of this.

[image: activities]

However, other apps do not - OneNote, Wunderlist, etc are not enabled by default.

Is there a setting in the plist file that controls this? I'm wondering if I can enable it by default, or have the user consent to enabling it by default, when my app starts up.

Thank you!

Comment: I think these are apps that either belong to or have made special arrangement with Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These apps have agreements with Apple. If you look at your settings app, you can see these apps that have agreements. Vimeo is another app with a similar agreement. As far as I know, there is no way to set your app to have the share extension enabled by default.

[image]

Note that I do not have Vimeo installed, but it's still in the Settings app.

Comment: Makes sense! I didn't know about that separate section in the settings page - that's really interesting. Thank you for the response!