# Set default app as ON in Active Screen ios xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Now i am using swift to code my app. I used share extentions and it runs well.
But I have a problem.
app set default value in active screen as OFF. I want to set default as ON. Do you have any solution?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, share extensions are turned off until the user manually enables them with the `More...` menu. That's just how iOS works and there is nothing you can do about it, other than instruct your user to open the share dialog and hit More to enable your app.

Only apps like Vimeo which have an agreement with Apple can default to visible in the share menu.

[Source + more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822171/5700898).