# Share extension iOS, how to enable my app in Activity sheet view?

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I have created a share extension for my app,
it works fine.
But my app is disabled in `ActivityView` as default.
How can I enable my app in `ActivityView` so that the user can see my app in the share sheet first time they install my app?

I don't know if this is possible or not, but look at the app LINE, it's always enabled every time I install it.

[image]

Comment: here is reference tutorial so please check once and try yourself : https://medium.com/@ales.musto/making-a-share-extension-that-accepts-text-and-urls-in-combination-with-coredata-swift-3-a0139c0f9800

Comment: You cannot do that , check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822171/8403513